# How do I create dynamic launch files?

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I developed a node which represent an agent in an emergent system that implements a collision avoidance algorithm.
Problem is, I need to perform multiple simulations with N robots, I know I can pass N as arg to launch file, but I can't find a way to launch N nodes in the launch file.

At the moment the only solution I have is to edit the launch file.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/229489/how-do-i-create-dynamic-launch-files?/) by [inusO](https://answers.ros.org/users/26327/inuso/) on ROS Answers with karma: 81 on 2016-03-18

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could use [eval](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML) (as of Kinetic) to create a recursive launchfile:

```
<launch> 

   <!-- start node -->
   <arg name="nr" default="1"/> 
   <group ns="$(eval 'turtle' + str(arg('nr')))">
      <node name="turtle" pkg="turtlesim" type="turtlesim_node"/>
   </group>

   <!-- recursively start new node -->
   <include file="$(find your_package)/launch/this_launch_file.launch" if="$(eval arg('nr') - 1 > 0)">
       <arg name="nr" value="$(eval arg('nr') - 1)"/>
   </include>

</launch>
```

As of Lunar you could also use $(dirname) instead of $(find your_package)/launch.

---

Originally posted by [MartinK](https://answers.ros.org/users/31019/martink/) with karma: 106 on 2018-04-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 9

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [raphael](https://answers.ros.org/users/38117/raphael/) on 2018-10-20**:
Does eval support the smaller than symbol, i.e. < ? I tried several time this code snippet, didn't work.

**Comment by [m.bahno](https://answers.ros.org/users/59901/m.bahno/) on 2020-09-22**:
For me, '>' does not work. However, I was able to use '>' with switched arguments, which is equivalent. Though I have no idea, why the first option doesn't work and throws Invalid XML syntax...

**Comment by [cgnarendiran](https://answers.ros.org/users/29494/cgnarendiran/) on 2021-05-12**:
I'm sorry, but I fail to understand how this is recursive? I tried this script by setting nr:=5 and it just launched the turtlesim node and my launch file once each.

**Comment by [harunresul](https://answers.ros.org/users/70259/harunresul/) on 2021-09-02**:
hey cgnarendiran. are you sure you set the 'this_launch_file.launch' correctly? the name must be same as your desired launch file. For example, if you have an example.launch file and want to launch it 5 times, you should set the nr=5 as the default. Then you should re-launch your example.launch file in  part. Include the example.launch file in that part by writing it's package, path and name correctly. This should work.

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2021-10-27**:
This is very very smart!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am not aware of a way to launch N instances of the node by passing N as a roslaunch parameter, however you can follow the approach given [here](https://github.com/micpalmia/youbot_ros_tools/wiki/Understanding-launch-and-namespaces)  : put the section of the roslaunch file that you want to replicate inside a namespace `ns` tag, and pass the value of this namespace as a command line argument. Then you can have a shell script that calls your roslaunch command (e.g `roslaunch youbot_gazebo youbot_gazebo ns:=/robot$i` ) in a loop, each time with a different namespace value.

---

Originally posted by [al-dev](https://answers.ros.org/users/18863/al-dev/) with karma: 883 on 2016-03-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As far as I found out, there is no way to do it with a launch file.
I solved it by writing a simple python program using the roslaunch API
(http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/API%20Usage)

---

Originally posted by [inusO](https://answers.ros.org/users/26327/inuso/) with karma: 81 on 2016-03-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [HatchEm27998](https://answers.ros.org/users/71710/hatchem27998/) on 2021-03-10**:
Thank you so so so much for this, this solved a problem we were facing for quite a while!